# Как указать устройство для запуска приложения в android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

Я добавил вирутальную машину на андроиде, она запускается, всё ок. Но я не могу добавить его в это меню:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я жму на созданное устройство, оно просто запускается, и не добавляется, как устройство для запуска. Как это исправить ?